# Complete game Troitzky-Vogt?

Tags: draw, famous-players, stalemate, famous-games

The [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stalemate#Troitzky_versus_Vogt) on stalemate shows a position where Vogt became victim of a diabolic stalemate trap set by Troitzky.

```
[Title "Troitzky-Vogt"]
[FEN "2kr4/1ppb1pp1/1b4r1/pP2p3/P3P3/5qN1/2Q2P1P/2R1B1KR w - - 0 1"]

1. Rd1! Bh3? 2. Rxd8+ Kxd8 3. Qd1+ Qxd1 1/2-1/2
```

I would like to have the full game. Can anyone help?

Comment: I found the original source for the Wikipedia reference (http://206.130.103.122/interim/magazine/1970s/MC7308.pdf, p. 6) but it includes just the same diagram and final moves.

Answer (score 8):

Not to rain on your hopes - but the problem you're looking for at first appeared in:

> *Troitzky*, A. (1924), **500 Endspielstudien**, Verlag Kagan, Berlin

Troitzky was an impeccable note-taker when it came to chess.  This book was End Game Studies and show endgame positions with only with a few endgame moves.  It didn't show complete games.

> Unfortunately [all of his notes were destroyed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexey_Troitsky) in the siege of Leningrad, so there is likely no record of this complete game (not even in Russian sources). (He also died of starvation during the same siege)

Please don't shoot the messenger.